# ΜongoDB PHP, Error: Call to undefined method MongoDB\Driver\Manager::getEncryptedFieldsMap()

Tags: php, mongodb

I am trying to create a collection on my **MongoDB** database using **PHP** but I am getting the following error

*Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method MongoDB\Driver\Manager::getEncryptedFieldsMap() *

I have downloaded and added the **MongoDB PHP Driver**, via the **php_mongodb.ddl** file (have made sure to download the correct driver version for my php version), and have added the **MongoDB PHP Library** via **Composer** using the **composer require jenssegers/mongodb --ignore-platform-reqs**, all with no errors.

My code is the following:

```
<?php



require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$client = new MongoDB\Client("mongodb://127.0.0.1/");

echo "connected succ <br><br>";

$db = $client->webVacSer;

echo "db sellected successfully <br><br>";

$collection = $db->createCollection("customers");
echo "collection created successfully <br><br>";




?>
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Why did you need to do `--ignore-platform-reqs`? Does `phpinfo()` show the extension properly installed?

Comment: @ceejayoz I run the command like that because  *composer require jenssegers/mongodb* wouldn't run on its own. Here is the result of running phpinfo() https://imgur.com/a/lXaNhVS.

Comment: You have v1.9 of the Mongo extension. https://www.php.net/manual/en/mongodb-driver-manager.getencryptedfieldsmap.php says that function didn't exist until v1.14.

Comment: @ceejayoz Hmm weird. I have just 
downloaded and added the 1.15 Mongo 
extension from 
[this source](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver/releases/), 
by drag and dropping the new *php_mongodb.dll file* *in the xamp/php/ext* directory. 
Now when I try to run the command `composer require mongodb/mongodb` 
I get [this](https://imgur.com/a/DjkUHeO) error message. 
Also [this](https://imgur.com/a/tmlkXyY) is the result of my new `phpinfo()`,
and bellow you can see that 
I am getting the error message *Uncaught Error: Class 
"MongoDB\Driver\Manager" not found*.